Two inertia js vue builds with laravel and modules (Module with SSR build)
We have our main project which had no modules within. It is a crm which does not use SSR but is just a inertia vue js project that gets built for production and used accordingly.
A recent requirement was that we add a retail site to the project. We decided to use laravel modules - https://laravelmodules.com/
The module because it will be client facing needs SSR enabled. It has its own vite.config.js file to configure but the base inertia is not playing nicely with it.
So i was wondering if this was possible that the module run with SSR enabled and the main CRM application carries on as intended.
Already, I've had to place my vue files for the module inside my main project resources/js/Pages
https://ibb.co/hmks1Q8
Here is a screenshot of my module directory:

Here is the main project including the module:

